# Takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

This is the code for a discord.py and it is for a clear/purge command.
My question is how would I fix this error message.

```
   @bot.command(pass_context=True)
   async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
     

   embed = discord.Embed(
    title = ' Success',
    description = 'I have deleted the messages.',
    colour = discord.Colour.blue()
     )
   
   await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
   sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
   time.sleep(3) 
   await ctx.message.delete(sent)
```

This is the error message

```
 Ignoring exception in command clear:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
        ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
      File "main.py", line 71, in clear
        await ctx.message.delete(sent)
    TypeError: delete() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: The code has `await ctx.message.delete(sent)`, but the error message has `await ctx.message.delete(embed)`.  Please post the actual code.  Also please post the full error traceback.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I posted the error info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***A few things I noticed:***

**1)** `time.sleep()` is kind of outdated, use `asyncio.sleep()` instead. You just need to add `import asyncio`.

**2)** The indentation is wrong and therefore the code cannot work like this.

**3)** You are overcomplicating some things as you can see in my **new code:**

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
    embed = discord.Embed(
    title=' Success',
    description='I have deleted the messages.',
    colour=discord.Colour.blue())

    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(3) # Use asyncio.sleep
    await sent.delete() # Delete our defined `sent` embed
```

Comment: Just a tiny thing, but what you also could use for this is `delete_after`. Something like `await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=3)`. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send